Long table error on cas-dc Elsevier double column manuscript
I am working on \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}manuscript. I tried to create a table (long/supertable); however, I was unable to do it. Could you please help me create a long table ( however, a long table is not workable in a double-column manuscript) for a double-clmn cas-dc manuscript?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{Ref} & \textbf{Model}         & \textbf{Accuracy} & \textbf{Size}  & \textbf{Parameter} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{Ref} & \textbf{Model}         & \textbf{Accuracy} & \textbf{Size}  & \textbf{Parameter} \\ \hline
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

2014 & 1   & CNN                    & 90\%                & 12MB           & 4M                 \\ \hline
2014 & 2   & ResNet                 & 92\%                & 15MB           & 5M                 \\ \hline
2014 & 3   & LSTM                   & 88\%                & 8MB            & 2M                 \\ \hline
2015 & 4   & GAN                    & 85\%                & 20MB           & 3M                 \\ \hline
2015 & 5   & Transformer            & 94\%                & 25MB           & 6M                 \\ \hline
2015 & 6   & VGG                    & 91\%                & 18MB           & 7M                 \\ \hline
2016 & 7   & BERT                   & 93\%                & 30MB           & 8M                 \\ \hline
2016 & 8   & BiLSTM                 & 87\%                & 10MB           & 3M                 \\ \hline
2016 & 9   & ResNeXt                & 96\%                & 22MB           & 4M                 \\ \hline
2017 & 10  & MobileNet              & 89\%                & 5MB            & 1M                 \\ \hline
2017 & 11  & DenseNet               & 93\%                & 17MB           & 6M                 \\ \hline
2017 & 12  & GPT-3                  & 97\%                & 100MB          & 175B               \\ \hline
2018 & 13  & EfficientNet           & 95\%                & 19MB           & 5M                 \\ \hline
2018 & 14  & CapsuleNet             & 88\%                & 14MB           & 4M                 \\ \hline
2018 & 15  & GRU                    & 91\%                & 9MB            & 2M                 \\ \hline
2018 & 16  & Xception               & 94\%                & 21MB           & 7M                 \\ \hline
2019 & 17  & Inception              & 90\%                & 16MB           & 5M                 \\ \hline
2019 & 18  & WaveNet                & 93\%                & 28MB           & 8M                 \\ \hline
2019 & 19  & ALBERT                 & 92\%                & 32MB           & 9M                 \\ \hline
2019 & 20  & Attention LSTM         & 86\%                & 12MB           & 4M                 \\ \hline
2020 & 21  & CapsuleGAN             & 89\%                & 24MB           & 6M                 \\ \hline
2020 & 22  & NASNet                 & 95\%                & 26MB           & 7M                 \\ \hline
2020 & 23  & ELMo                   & 88\%                & 11MB           & 3M                 \\ \hline
2020 & 24  & GPT-4                  & 98\%                & 120MB          & 200B               \\ \hline
2021 & 25  & MobileBERT             & 93\%                & 23MB           & 6M                 \\ \hline
2021 & 26  & ShuffleNet             & 91\%                & 6MB            & 2M                 \\ \hline
2021 & 27  & RoBERTa                & 94\%                & 35MB           & 10M                \\ \hline
2022 & 28  & CapsuleRNN             & 88\%                & 13MB           & 5M                 \\ \hline
2022 & 29  & SqueezeNet             & 87\%                & 4MB            & 1M                 \\ \hline
2022 & 30  & HRNet                  & 96\%                & 24MB           & 8M                 \\ \hline
2023 & 31  & T5                     & 95\%                & 150MB          & 300B               \\ \hline
2023 & 32  & Attentive LSTM         & 89\%                & 14MB           & 6M                 \\ \hline
2023 & 33  & MobileGPT              & 97\%                & 130MB          & 250B               \\ \hline
2023 & 34  & EfficientDet           & 92\%                & 45MB           & 12M                \\ \hline
2024 & 35  & XLNet                  & 94\%                & 40MB           & 11M                \\ \hline
2024 & 36  & CycleGAN               & 88\%                & 18MB           & 7M                 \\ \hline
2024 & 37  & Graph Convolutional NN & 91\%                & 32MB           & 9M                 \\ \hline
2024 & 38  & ERNIE                  & 96\%                & 38MB           & 13M                \\ \hline
2025 & 39  & SENet                  & 93\%                & 27MB           & 8M                 \\ \hline
2025 & 40  & Transformer-XL         & 95\%                & 55MB           & 15M                \\ \hline
2025 & 41  & StyleGAN               & 90\%                & 75MB           & 20M                \\ \hline
2025 & 42  & MixNet                 & 94\%                & 25MB           & 7M                 \\ \hline
2026 & 43  & UniLM                  & 97\%                & 180MB          & 350B               \\ \hline
2026 & 44  & PointNet               & 89\%                & 10MB           & 4M                 \\ \hline
2026 & 45  & Convolutional LSTM     & 92\%                & 15MB           & 5M                 \\ \hline
2026 & 46  & BigGAN                 & 96\%                & 120MB          & 300M               \\ \hline
2027 & 47  & MixNetv2               & 95\%                & 28MB           & 8M                 \\ \hline
2027 & 48  & SimCLR                 & 93\%                & 50MB           & 13M                \\ \hline
2027 & 49  & Variational Autoencoder& 88\%               & 12MB           & 3M                 \\ \hline
2027 & 50  & RegNet                 & 97\%                & 35MB           & 10M                \\ \hline
2028 & 51  & BERT-2                 & 94\%                & 40MB           & 12M                \\ \hline
2028 & 52  & StarGAN                & 91\%                & 22MB           & 6M                 \\ \hline
2028 & 53  & CapsuleGRU             & 90\%                & 16MB           & 4M                 \\ \hline
2028 & 54  & Transformer-2          & 96\%                & 60MB           & 18M                \\ \hline
2029 & 55  & PNASNet                & 93\%                & 25MB           & 7M                 \\ \hline
2029 & 56  & DALL-E                 & 98\%                & 200MB          & 400B               \\ \hline
2029 & 57  & Convolutional VAE      & 89\%                & 18MB           & 5M                 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}


The table is too wide to fit in a column.

There are 6 columns. I should fit in several pages in a double-column manuscript. \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
However, I am not going to fit it in a single column. @egreg

use \onecolumn before the table, and \twocolumn after it (if the publisher allows that)
